# Postgresql create a search configuration with custom stop word list

Tags: postgresql, full-text-indexing

For a particular full text search I need to modify the standard stopword file and exclude some words. What I did so far:

Copied `german.stop` to `german_modified.stop` and then
removed the words from `german_modified.stop`. Then:

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY public.german_nostop (
   TEMPLATE = pg_catalog.simple,
   STOPWORDS = german_modified
);

CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION public.german_nostop (
   COPY = pg_catalog.german
);

ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION public.german_nostop
   ALTER MAPPING
      FOR asciiword, asciihword, hword_asciipart, hword, hword_part, word
      WITH german_nostop;

CREATE INDEX body_idx ON comments
   USING gin (to_tsvector('german_nostop', body));
```

But when I do

```
SELECT body, autor
FROM comments
WHERE to_tsvector('german_nostop', body) @@ to_tsquery('wie');
```

I get:

```
NOTICE:  text-search query contains only stop words or doesn't contain lexemes, ignored
NOTICE:  text-search query contains only stop words or doesn't contain lexemes, ignored
NOTICE:  text-search query contains only stop words or doesn't contain lexemes, ignored
 body | autor
------+-------
(0 rows)
```

`'wie'` is the word that I removed from the modified stop words list. For some reason PostgreSQL did not use the new stoplist. I do not really want to modify the original since I do want to use the origal for other searches.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to add your text search configuration to the `to_tsquery` call.

You should write:

```
to_tsquery('german_nostop', 'wie')
```

`to_tsquery` also removes stopwords, and since it used the `german` configuration by default, `'wie'` was removed.

You can set `default_text_search_config` to `german_nostop` if you want your new text search configuration to be the default setting.

Comment: Thank you! For some reason I had to recreate the index but now it is working as expected.